# Search forward in command line history

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

With <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> you can search in previous commands. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> again, it will displays older previous commands.
The problem it that this search is "one way", it always displays older results each time you press <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>.

Right now, if I hit <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> too many times and miss the result I was actually looking for, I have to stop my search (<kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>) and restart it from the beginning.

Is there any command (<kbd>Ctrl + something</kbd> ) to search for "newer" results than the one currently displayed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash also has a forward history search, which is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

Often, this shortcut will be masked by the `stop` flow control key binding for the terminal (check with [`stty -a`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/stty.html)). This will make your terminal stop outputting anything—not quite what you want.

To get forward history search working, you have two options:

1. Disable the flow control altogether: `stty -ixon`
2. Bind flow control to something else, e.g. to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> with `stty stop ^X`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> should search the history "forward". Or whatever `bind -p` tells you is bound to `forward-search-history`.